# What is the system requirement for rtt-ros and orocos toolchain?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to install orocos toolchain and rtt-ros-integration following the instruction here
[github.com/orocos/rtt_ros_integration](https://github.com/orocos/rtt_ros_integration)

On Ubuntu 14.04, it seems totally no problem.

But on my Gentoo (no X), orocos toolchain seems no problem for catkin_make_isolated. But when catkin_make rtt-ros-integration, I got the following errors.  I have disabled  LUA for both platform. Ruby version: on Ubuntu   ruby 1.9.3p484 , on Gentoo ruby 2.0.0p645 . `env |grep ROS` and `env |grep RTT` show the same results.

Can anyone help me to figure out what is the problem on my Gentoo Linux?

Thanks

```
brian-fulin ws_catkin # catkin_make
Base path: /home/vms/ws_catkin
Source space: /home/vms/ws_catkin/src
Build space: /home/vms/ws_catkin/build
Devel space: /home/vms/ws_catkin/devel
Install space: /home/vms/ws_catkin/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/vms/ws_catkin/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j2 -l2" in "/home/vms/ws_catkin/build"
####
[  0%] Built target dlv_peripherals
Linking CXX shared library /home/vms/ws_catkin/devel/lib/librtt_ros-gnulinux.so
c++: error: defining: No such file or directory
c++: error: another: No such file or directory
c++: error: variable: No such file or directory
c++: error: in: No such file or directory
c++: error: terms: No such file or directory
c++: error: of: No such file or directory
c++: error: the: No such file or directory
c++: error: first/lib: No such file or directory
c++: error: #: No such file or directory
c++: error: If: No such file or directory
c++: error: some: No such file or directory
c++: error: RTT: No such file or directory
c++: error: headers: No such file or directory
c++: error: include: No such file or directory
c++: error: inline: No such file or directory
c++: error: calls: No such file or directory
c++: error: other: No such file or directory
c++: error: libraries,: No such file or directory
c++: error: we: No such file or directory
c++: error: need: No such file or directory
c++: error: to: No such file or directory
c++: error: specify: No such file or directory
c++: error: these: No such file or directory
c++: error: here: No such file or directory
c++: error: too.: No such file or directory
target/ros_pkg/rtt_ros_integration/rtt_ros/CMakeFiles/rtt_ros.dir/build.make:114: recipe for target '/home/vms/ws_catkin/devel/lib/librtt_ros-gnulinux.so' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/vms/ws_catkin/devel/lib/librtt_ros-gnulinux.so] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:505: recipe for target 'target/ros_pkg/rtt_ros_integration/rtt_ros/CMakeFiles/rtt_ros.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [target/ros_pkg/rtt_ros_integration/rtt_ros/CMakeFiles/rtt_ros.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Linking CXX shared library /home/vms/ws_catkin/devel/lib/orocos/gnulinux/rtt_ros/types/librtt-ros-primitives-typekit-gnulinux.so
c++: error: defining: No such file or directory
c++: error: another: No such file or directory
c++: error: variable: No such file or directory
c++: error: in: No such file or directory
c++: error: terms: No such file or directory
c++: error: of: No such file or directory
c++: error: the: No such file or directory
c++: error: first/lib: No such file or directory
c++: error: #: No such file or directory
c++: error: If: No such file or directory
c++: error: some: No such file or directory
c++: error: RTT: No such file or directory
c++: error: headers: No such file or directory
c++: error: include: No such file or directory
c++: error: inline: No such file or directory
c++: error: calls: No such file or directory
c++: error: other: No such file or directory
c++: error: libraries,: No such file or directory
c++: error: we: No such file or directory
c++: error: need: No such file or directory
c++: error: to: No such file or directory
c++: error: specify: No such file or directory
c++: error: these: No such file or directory
c++: error: here: No such file or directory
c++: error: too.: No such file or directory
target/ros_pkg/rtt_ros_integration/rtt_ros/CMakeFiles/rtt-ros-primitives-typekit.dir/build.make:413: recipe for target '/home/vms/ws_catkin/devel/lib/orocos/gnulinux/rtt_ros/types/librtt-ros-primitives-typekit-gnulinux.so' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/vms/ws_catkin/devel/lib/orocos/gnulinux/rtt_ros/types/librtt-ros-primitives-typekit-gnulinux.so] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:470: recipe for target 'target/ros_pkg/rtt_ros_integration/rtt_ros/CMakeFiles/rtt-ros-primitives-typekit.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [target/ros_pkg/rtt_ros_integration/rtt_ros/CMakeFiles/rtt-ros-primitives-typekit.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j2 -l2" failed
```

---

Edit: Thank you for your help. It looks like what you said.

I checked the `orocos-rtt-gnulinx.pc`, it seems correct for both Gentoo and Ubuntu. I mean those defined lib and include paths.

But the output of `pkg-config --libs orocos-rtt-gnulinux.pc` on Gentoo  is

```
-L/opt/ros/ws_orocos/install_isolated defining another variable in terms of the first/lib -lorocos-rtt-gnulinux -lpthread -lrt # If some RTT headers include inline calls other libra ries, we need to specify these here too.
```

How should I do with this?

---

Edit2: Now I got rtt-ros-integration built on Gentoo by reinstalling the pkgconfig (emerge dev-util/pkgconfig).

Great help from @gvdhoorn. Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222359/what-is-the-system-requirement-for-rtt-ros-and-orocos-toolchain?/) by [Fulin](https://answers.ros.org/users/683/fulin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-12-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-12-14**:
Please don't use answers to post updates to your original question. Either use comments, or better yet, *update* your question using the *edit* button/link. I've moved all the text you added to your original question for you this time.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-12-14**:
Also: if you feel your question has been answered, please mark it as such by ticking the checkmark next to the answer.

In this case, you might want to answer your own question (so tell us what you did to solve it), and then mark that as *the* answer. Other users will then know this is answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure, but those `error: defining: No such file or directory` errors seem more like issues with the build script (`CMakeLists.txt` or something else) than with your OS. It looks like a comment is being interpreted as a linking instruction. Maybe there is a typo in the script somewhere?

---

Edit: looks like there are two separate sentences used as linker input (or something like that):

> defining another variable in terms of the first

and

> If some RTT headers include inline calls other libraries we need to specify these here too

Googling for these turns up [orocos-toolchain/rtt/rtt/orocos-rtt.pc.in](https://github.com/orocos-toolchain/rtt/blob/ccbaa7c68a4fdffa4f979613d2d0230d0eb1252c/rtt/orocos-rtt.pc.in#L2), which seems to have these as comments in the `.pc` file:

```
...
exec_prefix=${prefix}  # defining another variable in terms of the first
...
Libs: -L${libdir} -lorocos-rtt-@OROCOS_TARGET@ @RTT_USER_LINK_LIBS@ @RTT_USER_LDFLAGS@ # If some RTT headers include inline calls to other libraries, we need to specify these here too.
...
```

Could it be that `pkg-config` on Gentoo is returning those comments as parts of the `Libs` variable?

Can you add the output of `pkg-config --libs orocos-rtt` to your original question?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1